# Can't convert column with pandas.to_numeric

Tags: python, pandas, converters

I have a column of data, here is a snip of it:

```
a = data["hs_directory"]["lat"][:5]

0     40.67029890700047
1      40.8276026690005
2    40.842414068000494
3     40.71067947100045
4    40.718810094000446
Name: lat, dtype: object
```

I try to convert it to numerical with python, but fail:

```
pandas.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce')
```

This line does nothing, the dtype is still "object" and I can't do mathematical operations with the column.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.convert`? Link [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) or try `df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))`

Comment: pandas.to_numeric is a newer version of pandas.convert, so one could say I tried it. But the second idea (`df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)`) worked! Thank you. It seems that I didn't think that new variable is necessary. So `df1 = pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce')` also works.

Comment: Are you reassigning the output of `to_numeric`, as it's not an inplace operation?  i.e. `a = pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce')`.

Comment: Yes, this was a mistake. I forgot this isn't an inplace operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, let me post the answer for future readers:

try:

```
df1=pd.to_numeric(a,errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I have a problem where this is also converting my datetimes to a numeric value and although they are already datetimes in the DF. Anyway to ignore the datetimes?

Comment: @hfrog713, it's not good policy to answer separate questions in the comments here on SO. This post is also over a year old so it may not get too much attention. If you have a question, go ahead and post it :) however, you may just need to specify which columns you want to convert.

Comment: I appreciate the comment Matt. What i ended up doing was selecting only those columns that were of dtype = "O" and it would exclude my datetimes and then applied to_numeric to those columns. I will keep in mind your comment for future questions. Thanks again.